# Boost asio: how to get/send messages from async tcp server in different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, tcp, asio

I'm fairly new to multithreading. I want to create a c++ async TCP server to send commands (coming from ui/command line) to a TCP client, and respond to commands coming from the TCP client.

I have a boost::asio async TCP server that can read and write TCP commands based on [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) example.  (using boost 1.70)
To make my main loop non-blocking I run io.service.run() in a seperate thread.
This works fine, but I don't know how to send/get messages to/from my server thread:

**How can I now send data from my main loop to my tcp server on the other thread?**
I tried using asio::post(functor), but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.
**How can I get incoming TCP data in my main function** (so I can handle it there?)
To get notified in my main loop of incoming tcp messages I have no idea what the usual way of doing that is. I can use shared memory for that but I think I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be.

I hope anyone can guide me in the right direction.

asyncTcpServer.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(tcp::socket socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
  {
  }

  void start()
  {
    do_read();
  }

private:
  void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }

  void do_write(std::size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
      socket_(io_service)
  {
    do_accept();
  }

private:
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
          }

          do_accept();
        });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_echo_server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    server s(io_service, std::atoi(argv[1]));

    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service));
    std::thread t1([&io_service]() {io_service.run();});
    t1.detach();

    std::cout << "t1 created " << std::endl;

    //boost::asio::post(io_service, do_write);


    t1.join();
    std::cout << "t1 joined " << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two std::deque<std::string>>. One called `fromMain` the other called `toMain`. Two `std::mutex` to protect concurrent access

Comment: So the shared memory method? mhh, I was hoping to be able to do it with a kind of callback but can't find that for boost

Comment: Shared memory usage means less memory copies. And once you get it to work you can replace the mutices with lighter atomics/lockfree solutions.

Comment: good point. Can you elaborate how to read the deque 'fromMain' in my tcpServer? I don't see how I can trigger a do_write(fromMain)

Comment: you can't join a thread after detaching it; I would not let the read callback call write; write from main and let the read callback handle the data

Comment: the call to write from my read function is to echo. Calling write from my main is exactly what I want, but I don't know how..